# Javascript checkbox onclick only with top one

Tags: javascript, php

I've got a small problem. 
Finally some code is working, but only with the first available checkbox. 
It should submit the form, which does, but again, only with one.

Used JavaScript:

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#opties').on('click', function(){
                if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        $('#frm').submit();
                    }
         });
    });
</script>
```

Used PHP checkbox form items

```
<li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="opties" name="opties_in[]" value="2240" checked > Item 2240</li>

<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info"><input type="checkbox" id="opties" name="opties_in[]" value="2251" >Item 2251</li>

<li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="opties" name="opties_in[]" value="2252" >Item 2252</li>

<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info"><input type="checkbox" id="opties" name="opties_in[]" value="2250" >Item 2250</li>
```

The second question, for later ;-), is that it needs do do the action onchange, not on click. But that should be easy.

Comment: `id` always unique, in your case all checkbox have same ids

Comment: Where's the php part?

Answer (score 0):

you should use 'class' instead of a 'id'
try to modify id="opties" by class="opties"

```
$('.opties').on('click', function(){
                if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        $('#frm').submit();
                    }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. Use [a validator](https://validator.nu).

An `id` must be **unique** in a document.

To identify a group of related elements, use a `class` attribute and a class selector (which starts with a `.`).

---

A checkbox is not a UI control that people expect to submit a form. You should strongly consider using a submit button instead.

e.g.

```
<button name="opties_in[2240]" value="turn off"> Item 2240 </button>
```

That would remove the need for JavaScript.